# Will Apple Pay work with Mobile Safari and If not why?

Tags: mobile-safari, applepay

I was asked to see whether apple pay will work with mobile safari and if possible to integrate into our current mobile website/website. When i did my research I found that it only works with a native app. Is that true and if so why it does not work with mobile safari? Mobile safari or any other browsers in this  case is also an native app and why cant apple expose the apple pay for browsers that websites can use using a javascript API?What are the risks?

Answer (score 0):

As of now Apple pay APIs are only available for native iOS apps. Javascript API though is obvious future of Apple pay, is sadly not available with iOS 8-9. 
Javascript API and browser (safari) is considered not secured enough (hackable) to be pass EPOS information from browser to website.

Chrome is integrating Wallet with browser as first step and hopefully in future we will  have payment API to websites as well as for native apps.

Answer (score -2):

Apple Pay uses NFC to get connected to EPOS for contactless payment and hence it follows device perspectives.
Apple Pay allows to interact with EPOS like PayPass,PayWave or online payments  using the encrypted cards which we stored in the PassBook App(accessed with Your Touch id) but it does not doing any payment procedures Thats why third party payment processors are listed on the official website.

http://techcrunch.com/2014/11/27/identity-wars-why-apple-pay-is-about-more-than-payments/

Comment: That's incorrect. Apple Pay creates and provides payment authorization tokens to both EPOS devices for in-store purchases (over NFC) and to iOS applications for online purchases (via the Apple Pay API). https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/

Comment: @peeja Yeah Dear, it definitely make online payments..But my intension was to explain that Apple Pay is not making "Payment Procedures" itself; it is dependent upon BrainWire,Stripes ,etc. like processors.

Comment: Okay, but that's not what the question is about. The question is whether it works with web apps in Mobile Safari.

Comment: The function of apple pay is to provide (from. The SE API from deutschTelekkom)  the authentication and transaction system that ensures a person has the intention to purchase something, is physically at the location, understands a the circumstances of the transaction.

For More Details: visit

(http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-make-Apple-Pay-work-with-iOS-apps-that-use-web-based-checkout-pages)